# Separating Lists Based on string match - Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list as below

```
hostlist = ['hosta', 'Linux', 'hostb', 'Windows', 'hostc', 'Windows', 'hostd', 'Linux']
```

Want to create two lists based on OStype

```
winlist = ['hostb','hostc']

unixlist = ['hosta','hostd']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're the one that set up/created this list somewhere else in your code, note that you should be using a dictionary instead: `{'Windows': ['hostb', 'hostc'], 'Linux': ['hosta', 'hostd']}`

Comment: Welcome to SO. In general, to generate helpful responses, it's useful to provide code demonstrating your attempt at solving the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

```
for host_name, operating_system in zip(hostlist[:-1:2], hostlist[1::2]):
    if operating_system == 'Linux':
        unixlist.append(host_name)
    elif operating_system == 'Windows':
        winlist.append(host_name)
```

Comment: Great, Works exactly as needed. Can you pleas explain what does zip do.

Comment: If `a = [1, 3, 5]` and `b = [2, 4, 6]` then `zip(a, b)` returns a list of two-tuples like `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]`. Think of it like zipping together two lists.

Comment: So `zip(somelist[:-1:2], somelist[1::2])` just iterates over non-overlapping chunks of size two

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list-comprehensions`:

```
>>> winlist = [hostlist[i] for i in range(0, len(hostlist), 2) if hostlist[i+1] == 'Windows']
>>> unixlist = [hostlist[i] for i in range(0, len(hostlist), 2) if hostlist[i+1] == 'Linux']
>>> winlist
['hostb', 'hostc']
>>> unixlist
['hosta', 'hostd']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve it. Assuming that the name always has OSType next to it, the simple iterative way is to go through the list

```
hostlist = ['hosta', 'Linux', 'hostb', 'Windows', 'hostc', 'Windows', 'hostd', 'Linux']

winList = []
unixList = []
temp = ''

for i in hostlist:
    if i is 'Linux':
      unixList.append(temp)
    elif i is 'Windows':
      winList.append(temp)
    else:
      temp = i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a defaultdict to easily create a dictionary of all OSes:

```
from collections import defaultdict
os_dict = defaultdict(list)
for host, os in zip(hostlist[::2], hostlist[1::2]):
    os_dict[os].append(host)
print(os_dict.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
hostlist = ['hosta', 'Linux', 'hostb', 'Windows', 'hostc', 'Windows', 'hostd', 'Linux']

winlist=[]
unixlist=[]

for j,i in enumerate(hostlist):
    if i=='Linux' or i=='Windows':
        try:
            if i=='Linux':
                unixlist.append(hostlist[j-1])
            else:
                winlist.append(hostlist[j-1])
        except IndexError:
            pass
```